# Is it secure to store SQL connection strings in a SQL user defined function for a winform app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, security, connection, app-config

I have googled for a long time for ways to secure the SQL connection string stored in a Winforms app. Encrypting the `app.config` (connection string included) of a Winforms app could be useful; however, it is not as safe as a webform app since the app is installed on user's PC. Any malicious users who want find out the connection string can reverse-engineer the app using the locally saved certificate to decrypt out the connection string.

Recently, I think of a possible way for protecting my connection string.

It is like this:

1. I'll create a read-only user and a read-write user using MS SQL Server Management Studio. The readonly user's connection string is located in the resource properties unencrypted. It is used to connect to SQL Server and check for the login passwords into my app.
2. Once the password has been checked, I will call a user defined SQL function (secret key included) which input is a ciphertext and return me the connection string to login the SQL Server with the read-write user account.

Will someone view my secret key hid in the user-defined function? Will this work to protect my connection string for logging in the read-write user account?

Comment: Does this mean that the connection strings are using service accounts with a hard-coded username and password?  Can you instead use the workstation user's actual identity to secure their access to the database?  So instead of having all users connect as the same SQL user, have them all connect as themselves and manage permissions on those accounts server-side.

Comment: Is this some central database that all your users directly connect to, or is the database one that your users stand up themselves? If the former, why? Is this connection over the local network or the internet?

Comment: Wait... I understand if you want to encrypt something away from the user/owner of laptop. But why can't this user see the connections string? Do they pass the laptop to other people?

Comment: you can change the architecture to have WinForms call rest api. and api will have a connection string secured. also winform call to apican be auth against WJToken or against AD

Comment: short answer: no, it is _not_ safe. longer answer: for the app to have access to the database, it needs the _unencrypted_ connection string at _some_ point in memory, and at that point it can be read by an attacker with access to the device _easily_

Comment: *Anything* that is running under the user's permissions can be accessed by them. They could for example attach a debugger, or read process memory. The solution here is to either use strong SQL permissions (only through stored procedures for example) or to have everything go through a web server. For the former, you could use Windows Authentication, so no password, and each user has their own specific permissions

Comment: @David Your suggestion is good, but is a little too complex for me to do.

Comment: @T.S. & Charlieface   I have tried Window Authentication, but the connection is quite easily blocked by firewalls. So, I use SQL server certification, which requires username and password in the connection string.  I don't want users to see the IP, username and password and modified the data in the server without using my app.  I hope I can find a way that can limit users connect to my SQL server only through my App. It seems its not so easy. Sigh=@

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers. After watching TimCorey's YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFncI9yfY-E), I think I am sort of knowing that my idea is too simple. Using stored procedures in a SQL server should be a safer choice than the user defined function.

Here I would like to make a summary, as suggested by Mouse Power and Charlieface, for a win-forms app to connect to a SQL server with more safety, we can get data from a SQL server either through:

(1) executing stored procedures (with limited permission) or through
(2) web APIs wherein SQL connections are made within the server.
Conventional encryption(using ASPNET_REGIIS) of connection string in web.config of a web-forms app can not be applied directly to the app.config of a winforms app.  This is because the app.config and its encrypted key are both located on the client side, so it is difficult to prevent any malicious users using reverse-engineering to crack out the connection string. Nevertheless, encrypting the connection string using a key hidden somewhere (in codes, file, or resource) is still suggested, as a preliminary protection.

Using a separate account for each connection may also be an option, but this may make the programming of SQL connections relatively more complicated.